# Put $k$ distint items into $n$ boxs with replacement, how many pattern that has only $i$ distinguishable items?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

For example, given $k=2$ items, $n=3$ boxs, we can have overall $2^3$ patterns:

```
   1    1    1
   2    1    1
   1    2    1
   2    2    1
   1    1    2
   2    1    2
   1    2    2
   2    2    2
```

in which a pattern that has $i=1$ distinguishable item is `111` or `222` and thus we have 2. Similarly, if $i=2$, we have `211` `121` `221` `112` `212` `122` and thus the number is 6. What are the results for the general $k,n,i$?

Comment: Hmm... you're looking for a formula that takes in $k$, $n$, $i$ and returns what you described, right?

Comment: By "only *i* distinguishable items", do you mean *exactly i* distinguishable items ?

Comment: yes, exactly i distinguishable item.